# What can be parameter of below method when i'll call it

Tags: java, wildcard

```
String viewDocumentationFor(Class<?> clazz) {}
```

If this method will be call by its class object then which kind of parameter can be pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter will be an object of type `Class`.  There are two main ways to get an object of type `Class`:

1. if `C` is a class, `C.class` is a "class literal" whose value is a `Class` object that refers to `C`.
2. if `x` is any object, `x.getClass()` is a `Class` object that tells you what class the object is.

There are other methods in classes in `java.lang.reflect` that return `Class` objects, as well as some methods in the `Class` class itself that can return a `Class` property of another `Class`, or look up a `Class` by giving it the name as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are passing the "class" as an argument.

This example is a bit circular but it demonstrates the class as argument.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        doSomething(Main.class);
    }

    public static void doSomething(Class<?> clazz) {
        System.out.println(clazz.getCanonicalName()); //prints Main
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html